# I want to write a bash program that check if divisble by 2 , 3 or both

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash program that check if Divisble by 2 , 3 or both . but it didnt work . How can I fix it?
here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter First Number of range :"
read a
echo "Enter Second Number of range :"
read b
echo "divisible by 2 : "
for (( i=$a; i<=$b; i++)); 
do
if [[ i%2==0 ]]; then
printf "$i "
fi
done
echo "divisible by 3 : "
for (( i=$a; i<=$b; i++)); 
do
if [[ i%3==0 ]]; then
printf "$i "
fi
done
```

Comment: `[[ i%2==0 ]]` and `[[ i%3==0 ]]` are wrong. Use `(( i%2==0 ))` and `(( i%3==0 ))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not seem to handle the condition of checking if a number is divisible by both 2 and 3.
Here is an example of a script that will also check for that condition.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
read -rp "Enter First Number of range :" a
read -rp "Enter Second Number of range :" b
clear
echo "$(tput setaf 2)Divisible by both 2 and 3 : $(tput sgr 0)" > divisible_by_both.txt
echo "$(tput setaf 3)Divisible by 2 : $(tput sgr 0)" > divisible_by_2.txt
echo "$(tput setaf 4)Divisible by 3 : $(tput sgr 0)" > divisible_by_3.txt
for ((i=a;i<=b;i++)); do
    if (( i%2==0 )) && (( i%3==0 )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$i" >> divisible_by_both.txt
    elif (( i%2==0 )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$i" >> divisible_by_2.txt
    elif (( i%3==0 )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$i" >> divisible_by_3.txt
    fi
done
cat divisible_by_both.txt && rm divisible_by_both.txt
cat divisible_by_2.txt && rm divisible_by_2.txt
cat divisible_by_3.txt && rm divisible_by_3.txt
```